# Plone:Calling external python script from plone page

Tags: python, plone, zope

I have some entries(say products in a database table) and i need to collect details of them on page load from the database.

I have a global python script(getValues) to fetch data.

How to call the script since the product are categorized and are present in different folders and the script resides in main folder "Products".

1. Books

   - Book1
   - Book2
2. Mobile

   - Mobile1
   - Mobile2
3. getValues

Book1,Book2,Mobile1,Mobile2 are my pages which has been created using plone interface (add New-->Page; not via ZMI)

what I tried is as follows:

```
<div tal:repeat="records context/getValues">
<span tal:replace="records/Name"></span>
<span tal:replace="records/Price"></span>
</div>
```

and my python script(getValues)

records = {'Name': 'Test','Price': 20,}
   return records

Any help or pointers would be great so that I can move ahead.

As per the suggestion received by you guys, here is my detailed question

[screenshot of the script added in portal_skins/custom](https://i.stack.imgur.com/QAAoV.png)

Why the script is not getting called on page load event ?
I need the python script to be called on page load event as Form Setup Script in PloneFormgen

Answer (score 2):

If you put your Python script in any folder under plone_skins it is available for every content item.

E.g. put your script called *foobar* to *custom* under `plone_skins`

Then you can call it:

```
  <div tal:repeat="records context/foobar">
```

Comment: To be exact, Not any folder but any folder found in the list of layers under the skin being used in the Properties tab of portal_skin.

Comment: I tried this one but it's not working.Please provide any pointer to proceed ahead